# Spring Data MongoDB return object converter

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I have a large documents with 50 different fields in it. Only few fields are required when I save this document. When I fetch that document though Spring Data MongoDB is it possible to eliminate `null` value fields from the object?

During the save Spring Data MongoDB does the same thing and only save those values which are not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Our `Query` class has a `fields()` method which returns a `Field` object that allows defining which fields to be read from the document ([Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Query.html)). Thus when executing the query object against a collection you get partial document back and thus a partially filled domain object.

Comment: Thanks Oliver for you quick reply here. I have some other trouble though. I used this in my code.

 @Query(value="{ 'id' : ?0, 'roles' : { $in : ?1 } }", fields="{ 'firstName' : 1, 'lastName' : 1}")
 public User findOneByIdAndRolesIn ( ObjectId id , List<Roles> roles );

as you can see i am getting a user object in return.

is there a way where we can use a small portion of the Object and provide to client.

like
{
"firstName":"amit",
"middleName":null,
"lastName":"kaushik"
}

and no middle name since it was null.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to simply create a class only containing the three fields and use that as return type for the finder method. This way you get the returned document projected onto the dedicated class. It might still be reasonable to restrict the fields to be read to the ones contained in the class to avoid the entire document being loaded.